# difference between .nil? and == nil

Tags: ruby

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I'm curious about this codeblock:

```
if remember_digest.nil?
    false
else
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end
```

is there a difference between `if remember_digest.nil?` and `if remember_digest == nil`, or is this just the author's preference?

Comment: While the result might be the same  would like to mention, that `== nil` is uncommon in Ruby, `nil?` is a more common Ruby idiom. And since `nil` is `falsey` you could also write `unless remember_digest` (without any further method calls)

Comment: I agree with @spickermann also there is an actual difference `Object#nil?` simply responds with `Qfalse` and `NilClass#nil?` is the only class that overrides this with `Qtrue` where as `==` will actually perform a comparison so while the result is the same the former has a lesser impact on the interpreter (albeit extremely minimal).

Comment: @engineersmnky `Qfalse` and such are really only relevant as C internals. `NilClass` (`nil`) and `FalseClass` (`false`) are their actual representations within Ruby.

Comment: Given `remember_digest` might reasonably be a `true` or `false` value you probably don't want to test vs `nil` specifically. You might want to do: `remember_digest and BCrypt::Password.new(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference. According to [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F), only `nil` object  responds `true` to `nil?`.

Comment: The only true difference(s) to me is `.nil?` is cleaner, more readable, and requires less typing :)